# Controller issue in relation with 2 models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a attachment model and controller for al my images on the site.

The relations are (polymorphic):

```
class House
  has_many :attachments, :as => :attachable
end

class Apartment
  has_many :attachments, :as => :attachable
end
```

The attachment controller looks like this to store the right variables.

```
class AttachmentController
  @appartment = Appartment.find(params[:apartment_id])
  @attachments = @appartment.attachments
end
```

this works on the apartment page/path. (apartment/1/assets) But on the house page (house/1/assets) I got the error message "Couldn't find Appartment without an ID"

How can I deal with this/best approach ? Conditions in the controller?

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to check which keys are present first, something like this:

```
class AttachmentController
  before_filter :prepare_attachable

  def index
    @attachments = @attachable.attachments
  end

  private

  def prepare_attachable
    if params.kas_key?(:apartment_id)
      @attachable = Apartment.where(:id => params[:apartment_id]).first
    elsif params.kas_key?(:house_id)
      @attachable = House.where(:id => params[:house_id]).first
    end
    raise ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound if @attachable.blank?
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Possible problem...

"Appartment" vs Apartment

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: However, if the author misspelled a model name, that'd be an error, and thus, an answer to OP's question. In either case this is a six-month-old question... are we really gonna dig this up from the grave? ;)

Comment: I was [reviewing](http://stackoverflow.com/review) answers. I didn't actually write this comment. It was posted automatically.